# What type of Application does SavedStateViewModelFactory requires

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-savedstate

I'm trying to save the state of some text into my main activity, I have made a factory that passes one dependency as constructor of my view model and also the SavedStateViewModelFactory in order to save the state of that text.

But I cant do an instance of that with just the owner context, it alsos requires Application, and I don't really know how to pass it since I dont have one in my app.

```
 class ViewModelFactory(val interactor: InteractorClass,val context:Context):ViewModelProvider.Factory {

            val stateHandle = SavedStateViewModelFactory(context)

            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return modelClass.getConstructor(InteractorClass::class.java).newInstance(interactor,stateHandle)
            }
        }
```

Then in my Instance I want to instance my ViewModel like this

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this,ViewModelFactory(InteractorClass(),this)).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Is there something that I'm not followin in the docs that I'm not aware off ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take an application instance with

```
val app = context.applicationContext as Application
```